# Is there an easy way to get longest word that contains a certain letter?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to get the largest word that contains the letter 'f' through a for loop, through my code I tried to make it as simple as possible with a if and and statement. It is however not working as it returns the largest word but not the one that includes the letter f, why is it not working?

```
def main():
    sentence = "Absence makes the heart grow fonder"
    letter = "f"
    longest_word = get_longest_word(sentence, letter)
    print('"' + longest_word + '" is the longest word containing the letter "'
          + letter + '".')

def get_longest_word(sentence, letter):
    words_list = sentence.split()
    largest = words_list[0]
    my_list = []
    for word in words_list:
        if letter in word and len(word) > len(largest):
            largest = word
    return largest 


main()
```

Comment: The problem is that you initialise `largest` to the first word, even if it doesn't have the sought letter. Initialise it to `''` and get rid of `my_list` (which you're not using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you initialise `largest` to `words_list[0]`, which is `'Absence'`, *the longest word in the sentence*.

Therefore, even when `'fonder'` is reached, even though the first part of your `if` passes (it contains an `'f'`), the second part about length does not.

Personally, I would just do this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get_longest_word(sentence, letter):
    words_with_letter = ((word, len(word)) for word in sentence.split() if letter in word)
    return max(words_with_letter, key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

This converts the sentence into an iterable of `tuples` where the first element is the word and the second its length, *and where all the words already contain the letter in question*.

Then, all we need to do is get the word with the longest length i.e. the highest value in the second position.

Output:

```
"fonder" is the longest word containing the letter "f".
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this much more easily using the `in` operator:

```
for word in word_list:
    if 'f' in word:
        longest_words.append(word)

longest_word = sorted(longest_words)[0]
```